# how to use stringWithContentsOfFile for reading image in ios

Tags: ios, nsstring, postdata

I am getting an error while using the following method for reading image.

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:imagepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error
```

The error is The file “image.png” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8).

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Sounds a bit strange to me to load a png image into a string ;-)

Comment: @d4Rk I want to send an image to a server with string format

Answer (score 0):

An image is always saved as `NSData` not as string

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagepath options:0 error:&error];
```

For sending the data to a server create a string for example base64 encoded but this depends on what format the server expects

```
if (data != nil) {
   NSString *string = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, what he wants.. could also be a base64 encoded string or whatever ;-)

Comment: @d4Rk A base64 encoded string doesn't cause this error  and `.png` points to an image file.

Comment: Ok, what about it is saved as data, and he wants do send it to the backend as base64? I would not do it like that, but totally possible, isn't it?

Comment: @d4Rk To *read* the file you have to use the `NSData` API anyway (or `UIImage` to create an image).

Comment: Whatever, just wanted to make my point, that it is totally not clear what he wants to do. (despite loading a image first)

Comment: @d4Rk  I want to send an image to a server with string format